# ASP.Net MVC: Where the user role is checking against supplied roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-roles

i am trying to getting hold on role and claim based auth.

just reading this article http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1102/aspnet-mvc-role-based-security

suppose a user login and he has sale role but action he try to access for admin role but i found no code where user role and supplied roles are compare to know user has admin role or not. see this area

```
private void IsUserAuthorized(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            // If the Result returns null then the user is Authorized 
            if (filterContext.Result == null)
                return;

            //If the user is Un-Authorized then Navigate to Auth Failed View 
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {

               // var result = new ViewResult { ViewName = View };
                var vr = new ViewResult();
                vr.ViewName = View;

                ViewDataDictionary dict = new ViewDataDictionary();
                dict.Add("Message", "Sorry you are not Authorized to Perform this Action");

                vr.ViewData = dict;

                var result = vr;

                filterContext.Result = result;
            }
        }

[AuthLog(Roles = "Manager")]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var Product = new ProductMaster();
    return View(Product);
}

[AuthLog(Roles = "Sales Executive")]
public ActionResult SaleProduct()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "This View is designed for the Sales Executive to Sale Product.";
    return View();
}
```

suppose a **user1** with role **"Sales Executive"** try to access **Create action** then where it is compare the **user1** has no role called Manager in code?
how this is happening ? who is doing things behind the curtain?

please help me to understand this only where this checking is done in code that **user1 has manager role or not** ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Notice that their `AuthLogAttribute` is inhereting from `AuthorizeAttribute`, then on the `OnAuthorization`, they are simply calling `AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(filterContext);`

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    IsUserAuthorized(filterContext);
}
```

After that call, they then call their own `IsUserAuthorized()` which checks to see if the `Result` property of `filterContext` was set or not by the base `AuthorizeAttribute`. If it is not null and the user is authenticated, the this means the user does not have the role required.

So to answer your question as to "where it is compare the user1 has no role called Manager in code", that would be the base `AuthorizeAttribute`.

I personally think there is little value in the `AuthLogAttribute` since it is just specifying a default error message along with which view to go to if the user is not in a required role. I would stick to using the standard `AuthorizeAttribute` instead.

Comment: sorry it is still not clear that how system detect user1 has role called manager or not. if user1 has no role called manager then redirect to error page. if possible please post a small working code.

Comment: Take a look at the source code for the AuthorizeAttribute. Specifically, line 102: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs#L102  It is checking to see if the user has any of the roles that were passed into the attribute

Comment: thanks for the link but these below lines are not clear `if (_usersSplit.Length > 0 && !_usersSplit.Contains(user.Identity.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (_rolesSplit.Length > 0 && !_rolesSplit.Any(user.IsInRole))
            {
                return false;
}`       please help me to understand.

Comment: Don't worry about `_usersSplit`. You are only working with roles...  `_rolesSplit` is a list that contain the roles that are required. In your example, you are specifying "Manager" for `Create()` and "Sales Executive" for `SaleProduct`. The important line is `_rolesSplit.Any(user.IsInRole))`. It is calling the `IsInRole(string)` method off of the Principal for each role in the `_rolesSplit` to see if the user has that role. If `IsInRoleIsInRole doesn't return true for any of the required roles, then it will return false.

Comment: how to debug .net code from VS2013 IDE. how could i debug the code for `IsAuthorized function` which is in dotnet assembly ?